# How can we do some processing before forwarding the request in Spring Cloud?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I have recently started using Spring Cloud. My use case is as follows:

Two types of services:

1. X (a spring cloud app acting as a reverse proxy)
2. A, B, C (spring boot applications deployed separately)

Whenever someone wants to access any endpoint in A, B or C, they make the request to X and X redirects them to A, B, C based on path. See application.yml for X:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: A
          uri: http://localhost:8081
          predicates:
            - Path=/a/**
        - id: B
          uri: http://localhost:8082
          predicates:
            - Path=/b/**
        - id: C
          uri: http://localhost:8083
          predicates:
            - Path=/c/**
```

This is working as expected and forwards request to the A, B, C.

Before forwarding though, we want to authenticate the request.

So the flow will be something like this:

1. Request comes to X
2. Request intercepted, data/request params fetched from that request
3. Request authenticated within X itself
4. If request is authenticated, then we forward the request to A, B, or C based on path

I am not able to understand how to do step 2 and 3. Step 1 and 4 are already defined in application.yml file and there is no separate code for that, just the main class. There are no rest controllers or anything.

The only 2 dependencies we have are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Let me know if there is some clarity needed in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar requirement in my project. I have to Authorize user based on jwt token. Please visit https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__developer_guide.html for configure your problem for pre authentication.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;

import com.google.common.net.HttpHeaders;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class AuthorizationHeaderFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthorizationHeaderFilter.Config> {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public AuthorizationHeaderFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }
    
    public static class Config {
        // TODO Put filter configuration here
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            if (!request.getHeaders().containsKey(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)) {
                return onError(exchange, "No Authorization header.", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            return chain.filter(exchange);

        };
    }

    private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange, String err, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);
        return response.setComplete();
    }

}
```

**Note : Apart form this code you have to configure your routes with filter in application.properties file.**

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=unique_id_for_endpoint
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://ENDPOINTROOT
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[2]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
##Rewriting URL Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/API/end/point/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/API/(?<segment>.*) ,/$\{segment}
```